# How can I connect to a already paired device?

Tags: android, bluetooth

I have my user inteface ready but I'm really stuck on how to create the logic to connect to a already paired device on my phone?.... I'm very new in all of this and I'll appreciate the help.

This is how I have my Main.java file:

```
package com.example.mustangsound;



import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void BTConnect (){


    }



    public void LightsOn (){



    }

    public void LightsOff (){

    }

    public void DoorsOpen (){

    }

    public void DoorsClose (){

    }

    public void SysOn (){

    }

    public void SysOff (){

    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

I want to add the code inside the public void BTConnect (). Again, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

BluetoothDevice device = mBluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice("bluetooth address of the device goes here");

Then you call a BluetoothDevice method to make whatever kind of connection you want. For example an RFCOMM connection would look like this:

BluetoothSocket socket = device.createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(UUID.fromString("0000111F-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB"));

for a handsfree device.

Comment: Well, what kind of device is it and what profile does it support. Also, what kind of Bluetooth connection are you trying to make?

Comment: I'm using this as MY Bluetooth receiver connected to an Arduino UNO board: http://www.miniinthebox.com/jy-mcu-hc-06-bluetooth-wireless-serial-port-module_p685429.html?currency=USD&litb_from=paid_adwords_shopping&gclid=CNWMh6ThprwCFRAS7Aod7iMAbw